# Branch.io API throwing SSLException Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0 on create

Tags: java, branch.io

I have code that uses the Branch.io API to create deep links on the fly. It worked for at least a year around 2017ish, and I'm not sure when it stopped working. I'm getting SSLException Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0 when I try to connect to the api at, "https://api.branch.io/v1/url". Anyone know what changed about the SSL security with the branch.io API to make the call no longer work? If I can figure out what changed then how to fix it should be obvious.

The relevant bits of code look like this:

```
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://api.branch.io/v1/url").openConnection();
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            out = conn.getOutputStream();

            out.write(bytes);
            in = conn.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: What version of Java, and has it changed? Any sysprops set, especially related to SNI? I don't know about 2017 but currently for ClientHello with missing (or wrong) SNI that server responds with two(!) invalid 'version 0.0' alerts (fatal 40 and warning 1) but it correctlyl rejects (with 70) ClientHello for version below 1.2, which would be the case for the (older) versions of Java that I know to omit SNI.

Comment: Java 8 and has not changed, nothing in the code base on my side has changed at all. I don't believe and sysprops are set.

Comment: Try running with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` (or if you can't do that get an external capture with wireshark, tcpdump, or similar) and see if your client is in fact sending correct SNI (which the Java log spells server_name). If not look at the _exact_ versions -- there were some bugs in this area, IIRC within the lifetime of j8 but I don't remember details.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I found that my cloud server is Openjdk 1.8 and I was using IBM J9 VM (jre 1.8.0). When I connect with OpenJDK both side it was working. Finally I resolved issue by using Spring [RestTemplate](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/) instead of HttpURLConnection and then with IBM jre also it worked.